# Best windows tool to scan and repair harddisk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Does anybody know a good software tool to scan and repair sectors on harddisks (an alternative to the standard that is included with windows e.g. scandisk/chkdsk)?

I know already about all emergency/ultimate boot cd's, I am looking for a tool that is not on one of the boot-cd's.

Thank you,
Kindest regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used and swear by [GRC's Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) for years.  It tries to recover data from the faulty sectors before remapping them (unlike chkdsk).

> "By operating directly upon magnetic
>   storage media at a level below any
>   installed operating system, this major
>   milestone release of SpinRite is able
>   to operate on all Windows XP NTFS
>   formats, all DOS FAT, all Linux file
>   systems, Novell, Macintosh (if
>   temporarily moved into a PC) or
>   anything else — it can even be used to
>   repair and recover the hard drive from
>   an ailing TiVo!
>
> SpinRite v6.0 achieves complete
>   operating system independence by
>   incorporating the FreeDOS operating
>   system. This allows it to be used on
>   any and all Intel/AMD PC systems. As
>   you can see from the Windows screen
>   image above, SpinRite 6.0 can create a
>   bootable diskette or generate a
>   standard, CD-R burnable ISO file to
>   create a "SpinRite boot CD". A
>   bootable SpinRite can also be
>   "installed" into any other motherboard
>   bootable devices, such as USB
>   flashdrives for easy, portable booting
>   and use."

I've made more than one drive stop 'clicking' long enough to copy data off it with this beauty. :)

It's not free, but it's only $90 to buy; which is probably less than the value of the data you're trying to save. :)

Comment: Stopped in to also recommend Spinrite. This has been a life saver on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I use [IOBit Advanced System Care Free](http://www.iobit.com/advancedwindowscareper.html). However, I used to with [that method](http://www.ehow.com/how_113636_fix-sectors-hardfix-sectors-hard.html) simply.

Answer (score 0):

[Piriform Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) is very powerfull FREE and simple program for files recovering.